# laws of joint distribution of several random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

How to solve problems of this type? random variables X and Yare independent and have a density $\mathbb{I}_{[0,\infty]}g(x)$.
Obtain an explicit formula and plot the density of a random variable
$Z=Y/(X+Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

One approach that sometimes works is to find
$$
\begin{split}
F_Z(z) &= \mathbb{P}[Z \le z] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y} \le z\right] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}\left[Y \le zX + zY\right] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}\left[zX + (z-1)Y \ge 0\right] \\
       &= \iint_D f(x,y) \ dxdy,
\end{split}
$$
where $D$ is the subset of the plane such that $zx + (z-1)y \ge 0$.

You know $f(x,y)$, can you finish this?